# Wordpress Searching a post in homepage by anchor links

Tags: php, html, wordpress, search, anchor

I own a wordpress site consisting in a single homepage with many portion of texts each of those are common wp posts and have an achor link in their title. I need to create a search widget which will search for a text by title and when the results will be available and clicked the page will scroll to the result according to the anchor itself. I'm asking myself if it is possible

Comment: It is possible. This is too broad for SO as is. Please add what you currently have and what you've tried.

Comment: I already have a scroll animation which goes to the anchor of the post in homepage by clicking from the menu item. I just need to create search widget and link it to this scroll animation thanks